# Play 2.3 override global SecurityHeadersFilter X-FRAME-OPTIONS for a specific action

Tags: scala, cors, playframework-2.3

I have enabled SecurityHeadersFilter globally in my Play 2.3.

This is my setting:

```
play.filters.headers.frameOptions="SAMEORIGIN"
```

But how can I override an action with X-Frame-Options=GOFORIT instead of SAMEORIGIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am using to avoid the header not getting overridden by SecurityHeadersFilter.

```
import play.api.libs.iteratee._
object FilterChainByRequestHeader {
  def apply[A](action: EssentialAction, filtersFun: (RequestHeader) => List[EssentialFilter]): EssentialAction = new EssentialAction {
    def apply(rh: RequestHeader): Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result] = {
      val chain = filtersFun(rh).reverse.foldLeft(action) { (a, i) => i(a) }
      chain(rh)
    }
  }
}

  val securityFilter = SecurityHeadersFilter()
  val defaultFilters = List(securityFilter)

  def filters(rh: RequestHeader) = {
    if (rh.path.startsWith("/cors_path")) 
      defaultFilters.filterNot(_.eq(securityFilter))
    else defaultFilters
  }
  override def doFilter(a: EssentialAction): EssentialAction = {
    FilterChainByRequestHeader(super.doFilter(a), filters)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use action composition.

First, create the Action :

```
import play.libs.F.Promise;
import play.mvc.Action.Simple;
import play.mvc.Http.Context;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class XFrameOptionAction extends Simple {

    @Override
    public Promise<Result> call(Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        ctx.response().setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "GOFORIT");
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }

}
```

Then, use it in your controller

```
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.mvc.With;

public class MyController extends Controller {

    @With(XFrameOptionAction.class)
    public static Result index() {
        return ok();
    }

}
```

This will add the header for the `index` action of `MyController`.
You can also place the annotation at controller level to make all the actions of your controller behave like this.
If you want to make it general to all your controllers, you need to create a controller that all your controllers will extend.

Comment: But how about SecurityHeadersFilter? I think the filter will override everything.

Comment: Just test and you'll have your answer... If `SecurityHeadersFilter` overrides your action composition, it means that it's applied after. There is a post about action composition order on the Google Group but I couldn't find it sorry.